# After upgrading aws-sdk-go package to v1.7.7 from v1.4.x. asws-sdk-go s3 client, upload file to blobstore failing with MalformedXML status code: 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I upgraded my aws-sdk-go package to v1.7.7 from v1.4.x.
I am using aws-sdk-go s3 client to connect to a blobstore.
After upgrading, upload multipart file(i.e POST) to blobstore is not working.
I am getting following error message:
MalformedXML: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema.
status code: 400
Following is the code snippet which was working in aws-sdk-go v1.4.x and is not working in v1.7.7.

```
uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(s.s)
svc := uploader.S3.(*s3.S3) 
svc.Handlers.Sign.Clear()
svc.Handlers.Sign.PushBack(SignV2)
result, err := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
                Body:   file,
                Bucket: &s.bucketName,
                Key:    &fileName,
                ContentType: &contentType,
            })
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? We are having the same issue with aws-sdk-go v1.4.4 giving us status code 400 with message "MalformedXML: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema" on the REST.POST.UPLOAD action, and we are kinda clueless here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Turns out this was likely caused by us trying to upload a 0-byte multipart part to s3. ERROR: The content that we try to upload is 0 bytes.